# Non-restrictive clauses / Correct comma use

Tags: punctuation, commas, non-restrictive

I'm not sure which of these sentences is best:

'There are a large number of alternative, sometimes dangerous interventions being performed on children with ASD.'

'There are a large number of alternative and sometimes dangerous interventions being performed on children with ASD.'

'There are a large number of alternative, and sometimes dangerous, interventions being performed on children with ASD.'

Comment: I like the last one best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the last one best, but the lack of commas in the second one cannot lead to misinterpretation, so it is fine as well. In this case it boils down to preference. 
However, the first one is, I think, wrong. You definitely need a comma after "dangerous" if you put one after "alternative."
(BTW, the correct sentence would begin: "There **is** a large number...")